# Can big omega of log n be the average time complexity of a binary search?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

I am aware that the average time complexity of a binary search is *O(log n)*. But since the concept of big/worse case scenario and upper and lower bounds are separate, is it right to say that the average time complexity of a binary search is ALSO *Ω(log n)*.

Most **importantly**, if it is right, why is that so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

Big-O, Ω and Θ are not related to the concepts of best, worse and average case time complexity. This is a common misconception. In fact, they are not even necessarily related to time complexity. They describe the asymptotic growth of mathematical functions, and you can use any of them to describe the best, worst or average time complexity of an algorithm. But you can also use them for some function that has nothing to with algorithms.

As for binary search, we know that both the worst and average case time complexity are logarithmic. So we can state that these complexities are both *Θ(log n)*. The best-case complexity, however, is not *Θ(log n)* because it is constant, *Θ(1)* (in such implementations that return as soon as a value is found). This is because if you happen to find the value you were looking for at the very start, then the time does not depend on the length of the input.

However, a function that is *Θ(log n)* is also *O(n)* and indeed *O(n<sup>100</sup>)*. This follows from the definition of big-O.

So in conclusion, the following statements are **true**:

- **Binary search worst-case time complexity and average time complexity**: *Θ(log n)*, *O(log n)*, *O(n<sup>100</sup>)*, *Ω(log n)*, *Ω(1)*.
- **Binary search best-case time complexity**: *Θ(1)*, *O(1)*, *O(log n)*, *O(n<sup>100</sup>)*, *Ω(1)*.

But e.g. saying that the average time complexity is *O(1)*, or *Ω(n)*, would be **false**.

Notice however, that if we say that an algorithm is *O(f(n))*, then we often try to express it with the tightest bound we can find. So you wouldn't normally go around telling people that binary search has *O(n)* time complexity - even if it is technically true. There are cases though where it is easy to prove *O(n)* but hard to prove *O(log n)*, and then it is perfectly correct to say *O(n)* even if *O(log n)* might also be true.

Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75792365/is-big-o-notation-used-to-denote-something-other-than-the-asymptote-of-a-worst-c) different but rather similar question and its excellent answer posted earlier today.